# gem installation error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Whenever I try installing anything using gem, I get this error -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ sudo gem install rhc
[sudo] password for murtaza: 
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/commander-4.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-17 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/commander-4.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-17 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

I am using rvm, but it seems it is pulling gems from the dir other than rvm. How do I remedy it?

It is also using the ruby installation from rvm as per below -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ which ruby
/home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using the system ruby, which is the default for your RVM and means it uses system paths instead of RVM paths. RVM paths are used with rubies that are installed via RVM. That's probably why you are seeing these paths.